# C - Value seems to pass to array element correctly but doesn't

Tags: c, arrays

Sorry I know that's a really badly worded question - I just couldn't think of a better way to say it.

I have asked this here as I cannot seem to word it correctly to find a solution my Googling.

Code explanation:

1. Separates file name 'echo' from file_name char array. file_name contains 'echo x y'
2. The loop starts at 'x' which is the previous file names length +1 (for the space).
3. The while loop loops until the next space is seen. The null char is to ensure the loop ends when the end of file_name is hit.
4. It assigns the value of file_name to arg_tmp until it hits a space then assigns this word / letter to the argv array
5. It then ++ the current_arg counter for the next arg

Hopefully this makes sense and there is enough code there to identify the problem.

MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH is 14

strlen(exec_name) = 4 so  the +1 makes it 5.

Length is 9.

Here is my code :

```
void
 setup_argv(const char *file_name, char *argv[], size_t argc, size_t length)
 {
   char exec_name[MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
   char arg_tmp[MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH]; // temp arg holder
   // get file name
   get_exec_name(file_name, exec_name);
   // add file name to argv
   argv[0] = exec_name;

   // get rest of args
   // +1 - start at first character of next arg
   int current_arg=1;
   for(size_t i = strlen(exec_name)+1; i < length; i++)
   {
     size_t j = 0;
     while(!(file_name[i] == NULL_CHAR || file_name[i] == SPACE))
     {
       arg_tmp[j] = file_name[i];
       printf("::WHILE::%s\n", arg_tmp);
       i++;
     }
     printf("::BOTH::%d %s\n", current_arg, arg_tmp);
     arg_tmp[++j] = NULL_CHAR;
     argv[current_arg] = arg_tmp;
     printf("::ARGV CUR ARG::%s\n", argv[current_arg]);
     printf("::ARGV::%s\n", argv[1]);
     printf("::CUR ARG::%d\n", current_arg);
     current_arg++;
     printf("::CUR ARG::%d\n", current_arg);
   }

   printf("::ARGV ALL::%s %s %s\n", argv[0], argv[1], argv[2]);
 }
```

Here is my output:

```
::WHILE::x
::BOTH::1 x
::ARGV CUR ARG::x
::ARGV::x
::CUR ARG::1
::CUR ARG::2
::WHILE::y
::BOTH::2 y
::ARGV CUR ARG::y
::ARGV::y
::CUR ARG::2
::CUR ARG::3
::ARGV ALL::echo y y
```

What should be printed in the last line is 'echo x y'.

I have used print statements to debug it and try to find where it goes wrong - but I can't seem to see it.

For some reason, it's printing and passing in y twice.

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT :  As I have now figured out - I cannot use malloc or strdup (unless I write my own functions for these). This is because I am doing an operating systems modules coursework.  Is there alternatives methods or should I look for written functions of these?

Comment: after all your `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` point to the same memory address of `arg_tmp`. To avoid this you need to allocate memory with `malloc` for `arg_tmp` on each iteration of `for` loop

Comment: Please, post a complete, compilable and verifiable program.  Snippets can be stripped of errors that can be the target of your question.  That way is not possible to make any diagnostic for your problem.

Comment: @LuisColorado Actually, the 3 people who commented or answered on this post (nearly 16 hours before you) all gave me helpful information and answers based off of the code given. Which led to me being able to solve the problem. If I were to upload a 'complete' program, it would thousands of lines long.

Comment: @AlexLord, the rules are there for your convenience, and they allow us to test your code without having extra work to do, and trying to guess if you, on writing the code snippet, haven't eliminated the error.  Errors are difficult to find.  And it is proven (or you would not be here asking) that you have one.  You can proceed as you like, but that makes our work more difficult, if not impossible.  And I have not written the rules.  There is not need of write a complete program... just add a main function to yours to make it compilable (and failing as you post)

Comment: that warrantees that you post a code snippet with the error included....

Comment: @AlexLord, look in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the reasons I expose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `argv` is an array of pointers, and you make *all* pointers in the loop point to the very same place, the first element of `arg_temp`.

This is even worse than you think, because when `setup_argv` returns, then the lifetime of `arg_temp` ends and it ceases to exist, leaving you with an array of stray and invalid pointers. Attempting to dereference them will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

As a solution I suggest you use the common `strdup` function, or make up your own string-duplication function which allocates new memory for the strings.

Lastly, for a correct `argv` style array, you should terminate it with a null pointer.

Comment: So would I do something like : arg = strdup(arg_tmp); ?

Comment: @AlexLord Close: `argv[current_arg] = strdup(arg_tmp)`. You also need to do this for `exec_name`.

Comment: NOTE :  As I have now figured out - I cannot use malloc or strdup (unless I write my own functions for these). This is because I am doing an operating systems modules coursework.  Is there alternatives methods or should I look for written functions of these?

Comment: @AlexLord Even an operating system kernel needs to dynamically allocate memory from time to time (unless it's for a minimal embedded system, when memory management needs special handling). So hopefully you should already have memory-management function in the kernel?

Comment: @Barmar Okay. I managed to find the malloc.c file and I found a custom strdup() function. So now it is working. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: The Unix kernel has `kmalloc()` I think.